# How to use server functions during initial render in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side

I was trying to create a dummy blog project to better comprehend Next 13 when I hit a block trying to crate a paginator. Currently I have a posts directory that runs on the server and uses a component called "PostPageComponent".

```
"use server";
import PostsPageComponent from "@/app/components/posts/Posts";

function PostsPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <PostsPageComponent />
    </>
  );
}

export default PostsPage;
```

Then I have the aforementioned component which runs on the client that has two functions, the "Posts" and "PostComponentsPage", where the first takes information from a local directory of the posts and lists them as an individual post, whereas the second one also adds a paginator component.

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

import getPosts from "@/app/lib/getPosts/getPosts";
import Link from "next/link";
import Paginator from "./Paginator";

export function Posts({ page = 1, read }) {
  const posts = getPosts(page, read);

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {Array.isArray(posts) &&
          posts.map((post) => {
            return (
              <li key={post.fileName}>
                <div>
                  <Link href={`/posts/${post.fileName}`}>
                    {post.fileName.replace(/\.mdx$/, "")}
                  </Link>
                  <p>{post.fileContents.slice(0, 50)}...</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            );
          })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default function PostsPageComponent() {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const postsPerPage = 10;
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Posts page={currentPage} read={postsPerPage} />

        <Paginator currentPage={currentPage} setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's the paginator.

```
export default function Paginator({ currentPage, setCurrentPage }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {currentPage > 1 && (
          <button onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}>
            Previous
          </button>
        )}

        <button onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And finally the "getPosts"  function.

```
"use server";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

export const getPostsDirectory = async () => {
  return path.join(process.cwd(), "posts");
};

export default async function getPosts(page = 1, n) {
  const startIndex = (page - 1) * n;
  const endIndex = page * n;
  const postsDirectory = await getPostsDirectory();
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory).splice(startIndex, endIndex);

  const posts = fileNames
    .map((fileName) => {
      const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${fileName}`);
      if (fs.statSync(fullPath).isFile()) {
        const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, "utf8");
        const parsedFileName = fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""); // Remove anything after (including) the dot
        return {
          fileName: parsedFileName,
          fileContents: fileContents,
        };
      }
    })
    .filter(Boolean);

  return posts;
}
```

I must also add that before I embarked this journey to add a paginator the core functions of the blog worked just fine, I am sorry for the spaghetti of code. I am not much experienced yet with the new Next.js.

And as always, thank you!

Comment: what is your question exactly?